# How do I create a new folder in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to know how I can create a new folder at some directory. How can I do it? I use `NSFileManager`.

Comment: I'm curious - why did you ask the question if you already know about NSFileManager? Were you having some difficulty that led you to think it might not be the right solution? If so, it might be more helpful to explain the problem more fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` method of NSFileManager:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
[ [ NSFileManager defaultManager ] createDirectoryAtPath: @"/My/Custom/Path" withIntermediateDirectories: YES attributes: nil error: NULL ];
```

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 5***

```
  let path = "/Users/\(NSUserName())/Downloads/custom"
   do {
       try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
   } catch{
       print(error)
  }
```